# Create UIView dynamically on number of letter

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2

i have already created views on number of letter, but i want to create like my sentence (Power fade) first five views and four views in between space included

[image]

here is my code..

```
for(i=0; i<strFinal?.characters.count; i++) {

        ansview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(viewwidth-5, 10, 30, 30))
        ansview.layer.cornerRadius = 0.2 * btn.bounds.size.width
        ansview.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        viewAnswer.addSubview(ansview)
        viewwidth = viewwidth + 35
 }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you be more detailed about what you want ? .. If you want to represent space then just leave that space (just increase xOffset) and add next view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I prepared for you some snipped code, only what you have to do to create temporary view controller named `ViewController` and paste code listed below:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let strFinal = "go man!"
        let commonSpacing = CGFloat(5)
        let spaceSpacing = CGFloat(30)

        var viewOffset = CGFloat(0)
        for(var i = 0; i < strFinal.characters.count ; i++) {

            let charView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(viewOffset, 10, 30, 30))
            charView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            view.addSubview(charView)

            let currCharacter = strFinal[i]

            var tempSpacing = commonSpacing
            if currCharacter == " " {
                tempSpacing = spaceSpacing
            }

            viewOffset = charView.frame.maxX + tempSpacing
        }
    }

}

extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
    }
}
```

I hope that this is good answer for your not exactly detailed asked question

Now you can customize this code according to your purposes.